# How to use a subquery in a where condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update only the rows, which gives me the select. How is this possible?

```
UPDATE user.table1 
  SET column = 'N'
where (
  select count( * ) number, colum1, clolum2 
  from user.table1
  group by colum1, clolum2 
  having count(*) = 1
);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.  Also, does your query reference one table or two?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Bad idea anyway. You shouldn't store data "computed" from other table data. Either add a computed column, or create a view. Or at least use triggers.

Answer (score 0):

The query can be constructed as follows:

```
`UPDATE user.table1 a
SET a.column =(SELECT COUNT(1)
              FROM table_name  b
              WHERE a.id=b.id
              AND a.mytype=b.mytype
         )
WHERE EXISTS( ....)`
```

Answer (score -1):

The WHERE-Statement is incomplete.

Example:
.... WHERE name = 'tispokes';

instead of *tispokes* you can use the subquery, afaik and iirc

also suitable:

```sql
... WHERE EXISTS (*your subquery*);
```

Comment: Could I add "Excists" after my where condition? So that every row which is selected will be updated?

Comment: Yes, *exists* is also suitable with your subquery